# Optimistic locking definition: expressed in terms of "lost update" and "stale read" detection

Tags: sql, database, database-design, distributed-computing

I am building a data service that must provide optimistic locking.  If my service throws an exception upon detection of either a "lost update" or a "stale read," is it correct to say that my service implements optimistic locking?  If not, what additional capabilities am I missing?

Comment: If you don't know what the informal term "optimistic" meant in the context of your assignment then you have agree to something without knowing what it is & you should speak to the person you are doing this for to pin it down. "Optimistic" is a general term in [concurrency control]( ;concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) meaning going ahead with work even though you might have to throw it away later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimistic locking is a protocol to avoid undoing intermediate third-party updates or intermediate third-party deletes that were issued in between an updater reading a resource and the same updater issuing an update(/delete) to that same resource.

But the essential characteristic of optimistic locking is that it achieves this without taking actual locks.  You can't say you've implemented optimistic locking if you achieve the aims by taking actual locks.

Comment: Erwin, thank you for your answer.  The design does not do any locking.  It uses data structures (copies of data, transaction ids on those copies, revision numbers etc.) to achieve isolation between transactions.  The design detects (and throws exceptions for) stale reads and lost updates prior to committing a transaction. So, would it be correct to characterize this design as supporting optimistic locking?

Comment: It would seem so but without any detail of your strategies/tactics/algorithms/... it's impossible for anyone to tell whether you got it right or wrong.

Comment: Fair enough, you've answered my question.  Thanks!